# Remove time values from a data frame which are within 10 seconds of each other in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing timestamps of visits to a location by RFID tagged individuals. Here is a simplified example

```
Time<- c("07:00:48", "11:45:34", "11:46:28","11:46:29", "11:47:17","11:47:18")
ID<- c("00003F9776","01103F9702","01103FA8DD","01103FA8DD","01103F9702","01103F9702")

df<- data.frame(Time, ID)
df
      Time         ID
1 07:00:48 00003F9776
2 11:45:34 01103F9702
3 11:46:28 01103FA8DD
4 11:46:29 01103FA8DD
5 11:47:17 01103F9702
6 11:47:18 01103F9702
```

All I want to do is remove the visits which are close to each other in time, say for example, if they within 10 seconds of each other. In the above example I'd remove rows 3 and 5.
My actual data sets contain thousands of entries like this. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one `dplyr` answer -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Timestamp = as.POSIXct(Time, format = '%T')) %>%
  filter(difftime(Timestamp, lag(Timestamp, default = first(Timestamp) - 11), units = 'sec') > 10) %>%
  select(-Timestamp)


#      Time         ID
#1 07:00:48 00003F9776
#2 11:45:34 01103F9702
#3 11:46:28 01103FA8DD
#4 11:47:17 01103F9702
```

To keep the first row in the output I used `default` value of `lag` as `first(Timestamp) - 11` so that it satisfies the condition (`difftime > 10`) to select the row.

Comment: thats remove also first row

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer to keep the 1st row.

Answer (score 1):

you could easy do this with `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)

df<- data.frame(Time, ID) %>% 
  as.data.table() %>% ## convert to table
  mutate(Time = as.ITime(Time)) ## Time as time
```

create `diff` col to filter

```
df[ , diff := difftime(Time, shift(Time), units="secs") ] %>% 
  filter(diff > 10 | is.na(diff))
```

thats all.

...or calculate & filter in one line

```
df[difftime(Time, shift(Time), units="secs") > 10 | is.na(difftime(Time, shift(Time), units="secs"))]
```

---

`is.na()` added to show also first row